# When i checked checkbox and after click detailsbutton,i need show me selectedrows details in popUp

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, popup, devexpress

When i checked checkbox and after click "detay"detailsbutton,i need to show me selectedrows details in popUp. I use devexpress aspx. How can i do guys please help me.

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZGE8.png)

[My Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftcc1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Refer: [ASPxGridView - Get selected rows on the server side](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T215644/aspxgridview-get-selected-rows-on-the-server-side)

> Use the server-side [ASPxGridView.GetSelectedFieldValues](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_GetSelectedFieldValuestopic) method to
>   retrieve selected values of the required column (a key column is the
>   ASPxGridView.KeyFieldName). Refer to the [How to delete the
>   ASPxGridView's selected rows](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E3076.aspx) Code Central example that illustrates
>   how to use this method.

**References**
[ASPxGridView - How to get selected rows on the server side](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T449255/aspxgridview-how-to-get-selected-rows-on-the-server-side)
[ASPxGridView - How to get selected row values on the server side](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q347704/aspxgridview-how-to-get-selected-row-values-on-the-server-side)